# Turn my stack into a string?

Tags: java, string, stack

```
String message = ""; //a string to store the whole message
for (int c = stack.length - 1; c >= 0; c--) {
message += ", "+stack[c];  //add the next element to the message
}
message = message.substring(2); //cut off the first ", "
return message;
```

This worked in solving my problem; thanks

Comment: the toString method will only return the top item in the Stack; the loop won't run through the whole stack like I need it to.

Comment: You pop each element out your stack and call to string. Read more about to string in http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/number_tostring.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling return in a loop will immediately exit the loop.  What you need to do is something like this:

```
String message = ""; //a string to store the whole message
for (int c = stack.length - 1; c >= 0; c--) {
  message += ", "+stack[c];  //add the next element to the message
}
message = message.substring(2); //cut off the first ", "
return message;
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Stream API:

```
Stack<Character> st = new Stack<>();
st.add('a');st.add('b');st.add('c');

String stStr = st.stream().map(s -> s.toString()).collect(Collectors.joining(""));

System.out.println(stStr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a StringBuilder to handle the toString creation. A template you could use is

```
public String toString(){
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
    output.append(this.getClass().getName());
    output.append("[");
    // append fields

    // to append the Stack you could use Arrays.toString
    // or just iterate as you are trying to do
    int i=top;

    do {
        T result = stack[top-i];
        i--;
        output.append(result != null?result.toString():"null");
    } while (i>=0);

    output.append("]");
    return output.toString();
}
```